Postgres Выбрать строки из всех таблиц БД содержащих нужное слово в конкретной колонке
Есть БД Postgres с несколькими таблицами.
В нескольких таблицах есть поле current_price varhar, которое может содержать слово %Defs%
Такой запрос возвращает все таблицы содержащие поле current_price
(select  table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME='current_price')

как к нему применить второе условие - вывести все записи current_price содержащие внутри слово %Defs% ?

Prepared statement, без вариантов.
